# validating file path for directory creation

Tags: c#, .net, path, directory

I am using `Directory.CreateDirectory(string)` method to create folders, now the problem is if the user enters string as:

`"C:\folder1"`  then it creates the folder in the respective location, fine by me.

but if he writes

`"C:\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\folder1"` it is also navigating to the same path, creates folder and not giving any error, this is a problem for me.

So in order to solve the above mentioned problem I try to do some validation before on the path and I tried with `Path.GetFullPath() and other Path methods` and I see:

```
Path.GetFullPath("C:\\\\folder1") no exception or error
Path.GetFullPath("C:\\\folder1") exception or error
```

somehow when the count of backslashes are in even number no exception is thrown but when the count is in odd number then exception is thrown.

How can I achieve this simple thing that when user enters path like:

```
C:\folder 1   valid path
C:\\\\\\folder1   invalid path
```

Please let me know if further details are required

Comment: This is because '\' is considered as an escape character. Therefore when you have an even number of '\', you escape the previous '\' so you would not get any errors.  But if you have 3 '\', you would as you are missing an escape character.  Look into escape characters and that may help you.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_character_escapes.htm

Comment: Is this a console application, Winforms, WPF? The last two have file/folder picker dialogs that you can use out the box that prevent this erroneous situation from arising. I would recommend that they select the parent folder path using a folder picking dialog, and then let them specify just the folder name.

Comment: @AleksandarZoric I looked into it, it could help when user enters odd number of backslashes then I could get validation errors and I could solve my issue, but if he writes even number of backslashes (doesnt matter how many) then I will still have the problem

Comment: Don't let a user insert a path like that in the first place. Use a tool to get the base folder (`FolderBrowserDialog` for WinForms, or something similar). Let the user insert just a folder name that you can test for invalid characters. You need to catch `UnauthorizedAccessException` and `ArgumentException` anyway.

Comment: Very dumb approach but maybe feasable: replace "\\" with "\" until string length does not change any more ... and check for [invalid path chars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars?view=netframework-4.7.2), I second that.

Comment: @3-14159265358979323846264 it is a wpf usercontrol. But I cannot use another dialog (cannot change UI workflow). I am doing all this in the combo box, and user enters path in editable combo box.

Comment: I would agree with @Jimi.  Use FolderBrowserDialog and let the user select/create a folder rather than asking them to input a path manually.

Comment: @Jimi cannot use another UI control, can it be done without additional dialog just using dialog functionality?

Comment: @Fildor replacing two backslashes with one if there are four then it could be two, but still this is a problem. Or you want to say something else?

Comment: @Newbie007 "...  until string length does not change any more " - that implies using a loop. But if you are in a GUI already, I'd rather suggest using a PickerDialog instead. You said you _cannot_ use another Dialog. But I read that as "want not". But reconsider. It will rid you of endless headaches.

Comment: ... 2/2 and if your Product Owner or Designer or Superior says "no" - there should be some serious discussion about that. If you need arguments for the FolderPicker, I am sure we can supply you with dozens ...

Comment: @Fildor I actually cannot use a dialog, its not my choice, I am obliged to do so :(. But if I dont find the solution, I will surely then look for the arguments to use a dialog

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution using `FolderBrowserDialog` - Users will not manually input the path but rather select/create it via  `FolderBrowserDialog`.

The below code will return all the files in a folder but you can amend it to return whatever information you need.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //
            // This event handler was created by double-clicking the window in the designer.
            // It runs on the program's startup routine.
            //
            DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //
                // The user selected a folder and pressed the OK button.
                // We print the number of files found.
                //
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
                MessageBox.Show("Files found: " + files.Length.ToString(), "Message");
            }
        }
```

[Code found here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/folderbrowserdialog)

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but I cannot add another dialog. Can we use dialog functionality somehow without its UI?

Comment: You could possibly use regular expression to check if the path is correct but that feels slightly too much work for the purpose.

Comment: _"You could possibly use regular expression to check"_ ... yeah. Then you'll have 2 Problems ...

Comment: exactly thats why I am running from regular expressions

Comment: What about calling `Path.GetFullPath` on the user input path.  Wouldn't that return to be invalid if an incorrect path structure was inputted? If so, you could run that check before executing the followed code.

Comment: That is the problem Path.GetFullPath does not return invalid when the backslashes' count are in even number

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a proper path from that, maybe you can use the following technique (in addition to what you already have, of course, this is only to remove the repeated backslashes)

- Split the path using the '\' character
- Remove the empty values (you can filter here the non valid
  characters, etc)
- Reconstruct the path string using join with the character '\' again

Something like:

```
        pathString = "C:\\\\\\folder1";
        splitString = pathString.Split('\\');

        nonEmpty = splitString.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x));

        reconstructed = string.Join("\\", nonEmpty.ToArray());
```

Test code here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qwVqv8

Comment: From my experience, it is not good to "fix" a bad input automagically. Either make it so the user cannot input bs (e.g. per PickerDialog) or let it crash and bubble up an errormessage so he actually realizes he put in nonsense.

Comment: I have to agree with you. The code in my answer can be also adapted to detect this case and ask the user to correct the input, of course. (for example, comparing the original input with the reconstructed one)

Answer (score 0):

What about sanitizing the path?

```
        char[] separator = new char[] { System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar };
        string inputPath = "C:\\\\\\\folder1";

        string[] chunks = inputPath.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string validPath = String.Join(new string(separator), chunks);
```

Comment: I am testing, will come back to u

Comment: I dont want to correct entered path from the user, I want to say that if he writes 
"C:\\\\\\\folder1" then its a wrong path.

Comment: @Newbie007 I've answered basically the same below (the code in this answer is nicer), and left you a fiddle to test this if you want to.  In the comments, I've mentioned that this technique could be used not only to correct the path, but to check if it is valid by comparing the original text and the reconstructed one (you have to do a little extra work to consider a leading '\' in the entered path): if they are the same, there are no repeated backslashes, right?

Comment: @GuillermoGerard: sorry for the late reply, if I see your code below you are just removing all the backslashes using split, right? the thing is I dont want to remove but if u see my question, I have said that if the slashes exceed I have to show error (i.e. invalid path, I have already done this using parser, thats not a big deal). and if I use your second bullet which is removing characters, I did using the library using Path.GetFullPath which as I said having strange behaviour with number of backslashes

Comment: @GuillermoGerard. so the main question is the filtering of characters in the path using some library e.g. Path or Directory or etc. because if u use the code Directory.Exists(@"C:\\\/"), it will also return true for some strange reason but if u write the same behaviour in file explorer combo box u get an error. e.g: "Windows cannot find "C:\\/". Check the spelling and try again". In short, want something like this